# Why doesn't the spell-checker work in question titles in Firefox?

Tags: support, edits, firefox, spelling

I rely on using the spellchecker when writing my posts.

I noticed that when I write in the title field the spell checker isn't available. In the body of the question the spellchecker does function correctly.
To prevent common spelling mistakes it would be preferred when the title was also spellchecked.

Is there something in how Stack Exchange have created the Ask Question page that prevent the spellchecking from working or is it a local setting that causes this discrepancy?

My browser is Firefox version 48, and I'm on Windows 7. I don't use plugins/add-ons for the spell-checking.

What are my options to also have the question title being spellchecked?

Comment: We don't provide a spellchecker for bodies either - your browser does.

Comment: As I know Firefox does spellchecking only for multiline edit boxes.

Comment: @rene : i don't know that this check comes from the browser itself !, and if someone has this question , he could write it as a comment rather than just downvote the question without any clarification

Comment: @rene : firefox

Comment: @rene : it's version `48` `windows 7` and i do't have any add-on or plugin to do that

Comment: This is kind of off topic here, as it's a Firefox issue, not really related to Stack Exchange. Any single line textbox won't have spellcheck in Firefox.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Where the browser ends and the site begins is fuzzy enough that it's an understandable question. Many people using SE won't be technical enough to know which parts of in-page behaviour aren't SE's doing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie true, and that's why I did not vote to close as off topic or downvoted. Just explained the likely reason why others did downvote. Seeing others did vote to close, I'll vote to reopen if/when it's closed.

Comment: On Super User: [How do I enable Firefox check spelling on single line text-boxes forever?](https://superuser.com/questions/129500/how-do-i-enable-firefox-check-spelling-on-single-line-text-boxes-forever)

Comment: Even this is a browser feature, there may be something that SE could do to facilitate it.  For example there may be an attribute on text inputs that instructs Firefox to spell check them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange doesn't provide spell checking at all. It is your browser doing that, and it does work for question titles too on Chrome:

> [image]

On Firefox though it can be an issue, although out of the control of the Stack Exchange developers. As [one user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/alexolut) commented:

> As I know Firefox does spellchecking only for multiline edit boxes.

Which is the issue you experience. Firefox has a support document on how to enable its spell checking feature for single-line edit boxes like the question title: [“How can I enable spell checking for a text box that is just one line, e.g. subject in e-mail?”](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/878123)

Comment: you can enable it in FF https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/878123

Comment: There is also our very own *[How do I enable Firefox check spelling on single line text-boxes forever?](http://superuser.com/questions/129500/how-do-i-enable-firefox-check-spelling-on-single-line-text-boxes-forever/129541#129541)*.

Answer (score 4):

Input elements in Firefox are not spell checked by default. Users can make it the default by changing `layout.spellcheckDefault` to `2` in `about:config` ([reference](https://superuser.com/a/129541/183672)).

Websites can enable spell check in single line input fields in Firefox using the `spellcheck="true"` attribute and value. Stack Exchange can (and should) add this attribute to the question title input. From:

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" placeholder="What&#39;s your bug, feature request, or meta-discussion topic? Be specific." class="ask-title-field js-ask-title" data-min-length="15" data-max-length="150">
```

to:

```
<input spellcheck="true" id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" placeholder="What&#39;s your bug, feature request, or meta-discussion topic? Be specific." class="ask-title-field js-ask-title" data-min-length="15" data-max-length="150">
```

([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck))

Since the value is inherited in Firefox, it can be set in the `<html>` tag so that every text input on a page gets spell checked:

```
<html spellcheck="true">
```

However, this would probably not be desirable if there are text boxes for things like "user name" that would commonly have text not matching dictionary words.